# How do I give a role permission to set a site variable?

Tags: 7, users

I have a custom variable in one of my modules and I want to be able to give permission to that variable to a specific role on my site.

I have the hook_permission function setup and I can see it in the **admin/people/permissions** interface, but I'm not sure how to implement a hook or whatever to give the user access to **admin/config/system/variable/edit/my_custom_variable**

Comment: I don't have "variable" in my "admin/config/system" path. What module are you using to provide direct variable editing capabilities?

Comment: He's using the `variable` https://drupal.org/project/variable module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to use something like https://drupal.org/project/config_perms to add a custom permission to the **admin/config/system/variable/edit/my_custom_variable** path. You can then use this custom permission to grant access to it.

Answer (score 0):

In hook_menu we have:

```
$items['admin/config/system/variable/edit/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'Edit variable',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('variable_edit_form', 5),
  'access callback' => 'variable_access',
  'access arguments' => array(5),
);
```

Now, what's `'access callback'`? By the [API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7):

> **"access callback"**: A function returning TRUE if the user has access rights to this menu item, and FALSE if not. It can also be a boolean constant instead of a function, and you can also use numeric values (will be cast to boolean). Defaults to user_access() unless a value is inherited from the parent menu item; only MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK items can inherit access callbacks. To use the user_access() default callback, you must specify the permission to check as 'access arguments' (see below).

So the module is using `function variable_access($variable, $account = NULL)` defined in the main `variable.module`. Now, this function uses data provided by `function variable_get_info($name = NULL, $options = array())`, that collects it's data from modules that implements `hook_variable_info()`.

**TL;DR**

In `hook_variable_info()` when defining your variable, set 'access' to an existing permission, or permission your module provides. Then simply give that permission to user roles that should be able to edit variable.